# Adding button to grid in Quickly

Tags: application-development, quickly

In Glade I made a grid 3x3 ad name it grid, I got instance of grid with

```py
self.grid = self.builder.get_object("grid")
```

and then I want to add for example a button on that grid when some other button named toolbuttonadd is clicked

```py
def on_toolbuttonadd_clicked(self, widget, data=None):
    button = Gtk.Button()
    self.grid.add(button)
```

and the problem is that button is not showing what evere I do. I even try with adding button to a box, with same result.

Comment: show_all and queue_draw are what you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

For Gtk.Grid, you should be calling it's [`attach`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkGrid.html#gtk-grid-attach) method, not `add`.  Also you need to call `show()` on your button before it will be visible.